# Calling array in shortcode issues

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, shortcode

I am condensing some area of duplicate code over multiple template into one shortcode that I can reuse easily.

I am calling the featured image url as an inline background image style at it works great! Here's the code.

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
     <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
         <div class="single-casestudy" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>'); background-size: 100%;">
              <div class="case-study-content">
                  <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                  <p><?php echo excerpt(22); ?></p>
              </div>
         </div>
     <?php endwhile ; ?>
```

This works fine when not in the shortcode, and I can see my featured image as the background on the live site, however when putting it into a shortcode function, it doesn't error, it just doesn't work! Heres the code I am using for the shortcode functionality. It seems like the $image[0] is not pulling through any data into the array.

```
function otherinfo_function() {
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'casestudy', 
                                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                    'orderby' => menu_order,
                                    'order' => RAND
                                );

            query_posts($args);

            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ),'single-post-thumbnail' );
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            echo $image[0];
                $output = $output . '<div class="single-casestudy" style="background-image: url(' . $image[0] .'); background-size: 100%;">';
                    $output = $output . '<div class="case-study-content">';

                        $output = $output . '<h4>' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
                        $output = $output . '<p>' . excerpt(22) . '</p>';

                    $output = $output . '</div>';
                $output = $output . '</div>';

            endwhile ;

        $output = $output . '</div>';
return $output;
}

add_shortcode('otherinfo', 'otherinfo_function');
```

If anyone could help that would super great!

Sam

Comment: First of all why you are using [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)? Please replace your post retriever with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) class or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) and let us know if issue still occurring.

Comment: Also the object `$post` within your shortcode is undefined. Please make it as `global $post` to first line of your function definition.

Comment: Adding $global post didn't fix the error

Comment: In reference to the first comment from @RahilWazir, [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) is worth a read.  And in reference to your last comment, `$global post` wouldn't fix the error - you've got your `$` in the wrong place.  It should be `global $post` as per Rahil's second comment.  And try moving the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` call into the loop (after `the_post();`).

Comment: Thank you @Hobo, don't know why I didn't think of moving it into the loop before! Thanks, it worked a treat